# Share text to Linkedin using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, linkedin-api

I am trying to share a text in LinkedIn using the Intent,and i searched a lot and used many codes,but not working..I saw many discussions also but cant find a proper answer for that.

How can i open the LinkedIn to share something through a button click.
I already used the following codes,

```
    if(Utils.doesPackageExist(getSherlockActivity(), "com.linkedin.android"))
{           
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setClassName("com.linkedin.android",
            "com.linkedin.android.home.UpdateStatusActivity"); 
    shareIntent.setType("text/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);           
    startActivity(shareIntent);
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Please install the LinkedIn app to share your result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

then

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setClassName("com.linkedin.android",
        "com.linkedin.android.infra.deeplink.DeepLinkHelperActivity"); 
shareIntent.setType("text/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);           
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

and some more,but not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this to share your text to linkedin

```
        Intent linkedinIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        linkedinIntent.setType("text/plain");
        linkedinIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text1);

        boolean linkedinAppFound = false;
        List<ResolveInfo> matches2 = getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(linkedinIntent, 0);

        for (ResolveInfo info : matches2) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith(
                    "com.linkedin")) {
                linkedinIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                linkedinAppFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (linkedinAppFound) {
            startActivity(linkedinIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"LinkedIn app not Insatlled in your mobile", 4).show();
        }
```

Comment: Hai sabish,thanks for the comment,i used and this error is coming,          Unable to find explicit activity class {com.linkedin.android/com.linkedin.android.home.UpdateStatusActivity};       have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? .what to do?

Comment: if its helpful for you please update the answer is correct.